# Is there a way to delete the same key from a list of objects within a nested field?

Tags: json, key, jq

I'm setting up a devops pipeline so that certain data profiles stored in JSON format can be shifted across different servers. While downloading it from the current server I need to clean up all the protected keys and unique identifiers. I'm looking for the cleanest way to do the following in JQ

Input:

```
{
   "TopKey1":{
      "some_key":"some_value"
   },
   "TopKey2":{
      "some_key2":"some_value2"
   },
   "KeytoSearch":[
      {
         "_id":"sdf",
         "non_relevant_key1":"val"
      },
      {
         "_id":"sdfdsdf",
         "non_relevant_key2":"val"
      },
      {
         "_id":"sgf",
         "non_relevant_key3":"val"
      }
   ]
}
```

Output:

```
{
   "TopKey1":{
      "some_key":"some_value"
   },
   "TopKey2":{
      "some_key2":"some_value2"
   },
   "KeytoSearch":[
      {
         "non_relevant_key1":"val"
      },
      {
         "non_relevant_key2":"val"
      },
      {
         "non_relevant_key3":"val"
      }
   ]
}
```

In python terms if this were a dictionary

```
for json_object in dictionary["KeytoSearch"]:
  json_object.pop("_id")
```

I've tried combinations of map and del but can't seem to figure out the nested indexing with this. The error messages I get are along the lines of `jq: error (at <stdin>:277): Cannot index string with string "_id"` which sort of tells me I haven't fundamentally understood how jq works or is to be used, but this is the route I need to go because using a Python script to clean up JSON objects is something I'd rather avoid

Comment: @Inian : Thanks for pointing that out I've edited my post and hopefully it should be clear now

Comment: @peak apologies I pasted it from the JSON validator into a set of curly braces which made it invalid, I hope the minimal/readability aspect is fine

Comment: fibonachoceres - No problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going with your input JSON and assuming there are other properties in your `KeytoSearch` object along with the `_id` fields, you could just do below.

```
jq 'del(.KeytoSearch[]._id)'
```

See [this jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/imiI1HeQXU) snippet for a demo. The quotes around the property key containing `_` are not needed as confirmed in one of the comments below. Some meta-characters (e.g. `.` in the property key values needs be accessed with quotes as `".id"`) needs to be quoted properly, but `_` is clearly not one of them.

Comment: Thank you this worked for me and also looks embarrassingly simple, I guess I missed the [] operator for array enumeration which is clear from the docs now.

Comment: Yeah, I knew I wanted to search for a post somewhere I read that some older version of `jq` needs this quotes to be present. Couldn't find an authoritative reference of which versions

Comment: Underscores have always been regarded as "alphanumeric" characters.  E.g. using jq 1.3: `echo '{"_": 1}' | jq-1.3 ._`

Answer (score 3):

> I've tried combinations of map and del

Good!  You were probably just missing the '|=' magic ingredient:

```
.Keytosearch |= map( del(._id) )
```

Answer (score 2):

alternatively, you could use a walk-path unix tool for JSON: **[`jtc`](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc/blob/master/User%20Guide.md)** and apply changes right into the sourse json file (`-f`):

```
bash $ jtc -fpw'[KeytoSearch]<_id>l:' file.json 
bash $ 
bash $ 
bash $ jtc file.json 
{
   "KeytoSearch": [
      {
         "non_relevant_key1": "val"
      },
      {
         "non_relevant_key2": "val"
      },
      {
         "non_relevant_key3": "val"
      }
   ],
   "TopKey1": {
      "some_key": "some_value"
   },
   "TopKey2": {
      "some_key2": "some_value2"
   }
}
bash $
```

if given json snippet is a part of a larger JSON (and `[KeytoSearch]` is not addressable from the root), then replace it with the search lexeme: `<KeytoSearch>l`.

PS> Disclosure: I'm the creator of the `jtc` tool